# Im confused if my CPU is compatiable with my RAM

Tags: memory

I recently bought an Asus M4A88TD-M-EVO-USB3 motherboard with an AMD x2 255 CPU with a 4G Kit ddr3 1600 Patriot- Sigature.

According to the specs of the motherboard 'Due to CPU spec., AMD 100 and 200 series CPUs support up to DDR3 1066Mhz.' My concern is would the RAM still work but not exceed the 1066, or is it not compatiable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The former. It will clock down.

Comment: That is not necessarily true, AMD is just saying they do not support speeds higher than 1066MHz.  Intel is the same way, they do not support RAM speed over 1333MHz for their i7 line, but I am currently running 2000MHz RAM and I have had it OCed to 2133 no problem.

Comment: If you don't adjust the settings, it will clock down.  (It's a waste of money in that case though)